# Serialization framework for .NET with migrations

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, migration

I'm used to working with Ruby / Rails and the ActiveRecord framework. One of the nice things about this framework is the migration strategy for defining DB schema. This means old versions of the database can always be upgraded automatically.

However now working with .NET I'm looking to create a file format to store user data for projects. XML is the obvious choice and serialization in .NET to XML is trivial. However as the project ages the serialization strategy may need to be changed. Fields might need renaming or moving around or have their types changed.

The use case is that a new version of the program has to load an old version of a project file this can happen automatically, perhaps with a message to the user that a migration of the file being loaded will occur.

Is there an existing serialization framework for .NET that can handle general schema versioning and migration or do I have to start from scratch?